# ListView ItemCommand Event not firing in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, listview, umbraco, umbraco7

I had taken asp.net ListView control in UserControl page. I am trying to fire ItemCommand event on click of Edit button inside ListView ItemTemplate.

It's working fine in Asp.net application, but when I integrate with Umbraco 7 as macro its not getting fired.

Can you please let me know how to fire ItemCommand event of ListView.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Could you post some code please? There should be no reason why it shouldn't work in Umbraco..

Comment: Show us whatever you have tried so far. Add some code snippets

Comment: Hello All, first of thanks for your comment(s). I don't know how but the issue has been solved, I just removed SelectMethod from ListView and all the commands from listview and button click event on page started to working which previously not working... Still I don't know what was the reason but now all commands working properly as it should perform :)